# phpmailer in while loop runs only once

Tags: php, email, while-loop, smtp, phpmailer

Everyday I've to send status updates to customers. The customer email id's are in DB. I'm using while loop to fetch the data and send the update one by one.

But only one mail is sent. Once the first mail is sent the script stops executing.

This is my code:

```
$result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT email_update_status_c, email_update_business_c, email_id1_for_update_c, email_id2_for_update_c, id_c, content FROM cases_cstm");


//include PHPMailer
require '../test/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    if($row['email_update_status_c'] == 1 || $row['email_update_business_c'] == 1) {

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $content = $row['content'];
        $subject = 'Document Request for ' . $row['subject'];

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
        $mail->isSMTP();     
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.critsend.com'; 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;            
        $mail->Username = 'my_user_id';
        $mail->Password = 'password';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;

        $mail->From = 'no-reply@mysite.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'Internal Underwriting';

        foreach ($email_address as $to) {
            $mail->AddAddress($to);
        }

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $content;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Send();
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using critsend services.

**Observation**

Looks like the $mail->Send() opens and closes a smtp connection. Once the first mail is sent the connection is closed and the while loop never runs again.

Can any one help me how to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: What have you done to test if your while loop isn't meeting it's ending condition? If the while loop never runs more than once, it stands to reason that something might be wrong in your clause.

Comment: multiple syntax errors: `$row[content]` is incorrect - arrays keys must be quoted, unless they're in a `"`-quoted string.  and if the loop executes only once, then your query only returned one row, or none of the conditions you're testing for in the `if()` match more than once.

Comment: Sorry I dint mean 'while loop never runs more than once'. I meant while loop stops running after the first mail is sent.

Comment: @MarcB I'm pretty sure query returns more than one row (have checked in DB) which matches if conditions

Comment: "pretty sure" isn't good enough. don't ASSUME.in fact, NEVER ASSUME. **CONFIRM**: put in an `else` clause with `"Ooops. if failed"` or whatever.

Comment: I've checked in DB. There are 8 'rows' which matches the condition. So there should be 8 emails going out. But its not happening.

Comment: I'd use a `WHERE` clause instead and using the row for the email addresses. Probably why it's failing.

Comment: @hellcode the subject and the content involves several lines of code. I'm also using the email template and I place the content block inside it. I see that this part of the code has nothing to do with the loop failing. So I dint put it here. So while replacing it I've missed syntax.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks. I'll try it out.

Comment: This is quite inefficient code. You should follow [the mailing list example that's provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).